# Morally speaking, 1+1=2

Tags: expressions, dialects, technical

I asked a question over on math.SE and as part of an exchange someone said:

> **Morally** the function is *csc φ* in the limit for the reason you mention.

...a pretty funny thing to say. I asked them about it and they said that,

> It is a figure of speech sometimes used in mathematics and physics

and that one interpretation might be

> What follows may be wrong in detail, or not contain enough detail, but it gives the right intuition.

Does anyone know about how this started, or have any other understanding of what it means? Are there any parallels elsewhere?

Even if used figuratively it betrays something quite strong about one's  philosophical attitude, or that of one's community. For this reason I am quite interested in this turn of phrase. Does it reflect a lack of seriousness or respect for moral questions, or does it simply acknowledge that mathematical and social realities are different?

Anything that can help me understand would be appreciated.

**Edit:**

To be clear, I would **like to know** if it has an implication regarding the value of moral reasoning. *If* it has the implication that moral reasoning is less rigorous, then it is certainly a *possibility*. Please do not take my question as an assertion of what it does mean.

Although some might find asking this outside the community in which it is used a little strange, there is one reason, and one excuse for this:

1. The word is probably used elsewhere in a similar way.
2. There's probably some mathematicians here.

**Edit:**

A coincidental discovery: There is such a thing as [a moral graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moral_graph), which seemingly has a rather esoteric etymology.

Comment: It means that 1+1=3 for large values of 1.

Comment: @MετάEd ... so how do I downvote a comment? ;)

Comment: Interesting question Lucas. I'd rather hear from a mathematician describing the use of the word instead of others postulating on what sentiment it might entail.

Comment: It is a bit metaphorical and provocative. It is a recognition that though the thrust of mathematical presentation is rigor and exactness, communicating about mathematical ideas can sometimes be the artistic truth. Some of Euler's proofs had 'moral' certainty despite missing some rigor. 'Moral' is shorthand for 'If you ignore certain unimportant details, this -must- be right, and you should be able to recognize that.'

Comment: "Sometimes 2+2=4, Winston. Sometimes they are five. Sometimes they are three. Sometimes they are all of them at once. You must try harder. It is not easy to become sane." Perhaps this was Orwell's take on moral certainty.

Comment: Seems it has a lot of parallels with the popular idiom "moral equivalent".

Answer (score 8):

The phrases *morally certain*  and *moral certainty* are not restricted to the math and physics communities; they been current in English since the 17th century, and I have heard and read them all my life in literary and colloquial contexts. *OED 1* gives *s.v.* **Moral, 11.**

> Used to designate that kind of of probable evidence that rests on a knowledge of the general tendencies of human nature, or of the character of particular individuals or classes of men ; **often in looser use, applied to all evidence which is merely probable and not demonstrative**. [my emphasis] *Moral certainty* : a practical certainty resulting from moral evidence; a degree of probability so great as to admit of no reasonable doubt ; also, something which is morally certain. […]
>    This use of the word is prob. ultimately connected with Aristotle’s *ἠθική πίστις*, which means the effect of the known personal character of an orator in producing conviction.
>    The currency of the terms *certitudo, evidentia moralis* appears to be due to the Cartesian logicians of the 17th c.

A typical early citation there is this, from about 1677:

> **H<sub><sup>ALE</sup></sub>** *Prim. Orig. Man*, <sub><sup>II</sup></sub>. i. 128 Though the evidence be still in its own nature but moral, and not simply demonstrative or infallible.

*Morally* in this sense is thus grounded in the Classical use of the Latin term *moral* (which, like the corresponding Greek term *ethical* derives from a word meaning ‘local custom’) to designate what rests on practical rather than logical judgments.

Answer (score 5):

In mathematical contexts, I would use "Morally such-and-such is the case" to mean "Such-and-such ought to be the case".  In somewhat more detail, it would mean that I expect there to be a theorem whose main content is "such-and-such" but which might require some hypotheses or some exceptions that I haven't thought about (or that I have thought about and will tell you but only after I've given you the main idea, "such-and-such").

I believe this mathematical usage of "morally" is somewhat different from the notion of "moral certainty" described in StoneyB's answer. The latter seems to refer to a situation where we have (or think we have) all the details but insufficient evidence for complete certainty.  The mathematical notion usually refers to a situation where we don't have all the details yet (or at least we're not confident that we have them all).  Incidentally, I believe the phrase "moral certainty" is also used in moral theology to mean a level of certainty sufficient to support moral decisions and judgments.

Answer (score 2):

> *Even if used figuratively it betrays something quite strong about one's philosophical attitude, or that of one's community. For this reason I am quite interested in this turn of phrase. Does it reflect a lack of seriousness or respect for moral questions, or does it simply acknowledge that mathematical and social realities are different?*

I completely disagree with that sentiment. I don't think it shows a lack of seriousness for moral questions at all; rather, I think it demonstrates how much that community values rigorous proofs as opposed to unproven generalizations. Such a figure of speech may illustrate how much that community values methodically establishing the validity of assertions – but that doesn't necessarily devalue their views on ethics and morals.

I'm sure other examples abound. Consider a baker who says:

> *It would be a sin to use Splenda instead of sugar in my apple pie!*

or a silversmith jeweler who playfully says,

> *Sorry, using pewter to make a necklace would be against my religion*.

I'd interpret both of those statements to mean that these two have strong feelings about something in their realm of expertise – but I think it would be wrong to presume that the baker and silversmith must not regularly attend traditional religious ceremonies, or that they are people who don't most likely have strong moral principles. Only the most adamant fundamentalist would consider it sacrilegious to borrow from the language of religion in order to express zeal and fervor about something.

I could speculate as to how *morally* came to mean *generally* in the math and physics communities (it doesn't seem like a huge stretch to me, based on my interaction with mathematicians), but I'd rather someone more steeped in those sciences do that. Still, it doesn't seem like a stretch to me at all, and I can't see how it might reflect a lack of seriousness or respect toward moral questions.

`EDIT:` Such usages of words can be found in news articles, for example, a career advice columnist entitled a column [8 Things It Would Be A Sin To Skimp On](https://www.voiceoverxtra.com/article.htm?id=6teiw9zw) when dishing out 8 nuggets of advice, and the U.K.'s [Telegraph](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/sport/olympics/8377424/London-2012-Olympics-it-would-be-a-sin-if-Great-Britain-are-excluded-from-the-Games-says-Pops-Mensah-Bonsu.html) once proclaimed in a headline:

> **London 2012 Olympics: it would be a sin if Great Britain are excluded from the Games**
>   *It would be a sin, nothing less, if FIBA vote not to allow Great Britain to compete at the Olympics next year*.

Comment: Please see my edit. Personally, if someone says "It would be a sin..." I think it says something about them and the community they live in. Moreover, I think it says something about what they think "sin" is. There is something shared between "sinning" and "using sugar in apple pie". My question is what is shared between "moral thinking" and "mathematical handwaving", there are different meanings depending on what is shared.

Comment: @Lucas: A theologian would define sinning as a moral lapse, or "missing the mark" in an endeavor to follow religious commandments. The baker might agree with that, despite calling it a "sin" to use an artificial sweetener. It's a lighthearted use of the word, one [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/sin) supports in Def 2a (as opposed to Defs 1 & 2). In much the same way, I don't think using the word _morally_ in the context you describe necessarily implies moral reasoning is somehow weaker or inferior to mathematical proofs – though opinions may vary.

Comment: I guess the reason I think there is a little more substance to it is that one is generally less inclined to be lighthearted about things one takes seriously - a priest may be disinclined to use the word "sin" in the 2a sense as it could suggest the matters of sin should be treated lightly. Another example, though quite an extreme one in comparison, is that of casual racism. If one wishes to be treated seriously as non-racist, it is better to avoid making lighthearted but racist jokes. Being lighthearted seems to me to indicate that one is not otherwise invested in it as a serious matter.

Comment: Maybe _metaphorical_ is a better word than _lighthearted_. An engineer might say of his marriage, "Back to the drawing board," or a veterinarian might say, "It's raining cats and dogs," or a pitcher might tell a friend about how he "balked" at a sales pitch, or a judge might tell his children that he intends to "lay down the law" about curfew, or a fireman might speak of "putting out fires" at a town meeting. Such expressions don't mean any of those folks take their profession any less seriously. I don't see an "implication regarding the value of moral reasoning" – that seems a stretch.

Comment: -1 This does not answer the question or provide references.

Comment: I like Mitch's characterisation above: "metaphorical and provocative". The difference between these and the case in hand is that everyone would agree or know of their meaning, but you must have a particular attitude to intuitively see a similarity between moral and some types of mathematical reasoning. As for it implying a particular valuation, I agree with you about it not being necessary. For now I can only think of neutral and negative implications, so to be convinced it is not a stretch I really need evidence against the negative interpreations, rather than an absence of evidence for them.

Comment: I cut a few too many words there.

Comment: @user867 I think the intention of this answer was to point out that I was being a little presumptive in the way I originally phrased the question (it hasn't changed except for where marked), J.R. was right about that even if I otherwise disagree with him. Although he didn't really answer the question, it was a constructive thing to add. I hope you will reconsider.

Comment: @Lucas Oughtn't he have made it a comment, then?

Comment: @user867 maybe.

Comment: @user867: It started as a comment, but wouldn't fit into 600 characters. In any case, it prompted an interesting and constructive conversation with the O.P. (who even edited the question, and has kindly defended my answer). I added a few outside references that may or may not appease you – the O.P.'s comments have been reward enough for my efforts, though.

Comment: @Lucas: I'll never forget one professor I had in grad school; he had a penchant for blurting out, "Can you prove that?" whenever someone made any kind of assertion (like, "But there's no way to do that," or, "Those two lines will intersect"). Not surprisingly, he had a math background. I don't remember him using _morally_ during discussions, but I remember he'd ask about proofs with a religious fervor. It was all good, though; his constant challenges made his students much more careful about stepping into minefields of presumption. I remember him fondly each time I revisit this question.

Comment: @J.R. Thanks for adding the reference, and I agree that the discussion is interesting. However, this isn't a discussion forum - being 'interesting' isn't enough to make the cut. This particular question was specifically about the origins and meaning of the word 'morally' in the context of mathematical proof; Your answer is largely tangential, and the part that does discuss the meaning of the word is speculative. Valuable though your insight is, the stack exchange format requires us to stay on-topic in answers if the utility of the site is to be maintained.

Comment: @user867: Fair enough, although it's going to be very hard to get into the minds of mathemeticians, and determine if the ones who use _morally_ in such a context tend to dismiss moral reasoning more easily than the bulk of society. Mathemticians and physicists are hard enough to understand as it is :^)

Comment: @J.R. Fortunately, it's not necessary that we get into their minds - we just need some instances of their use of the word from which its meaning and history can be gleaned. Like any etymology question, really.

Comment: @user867: I think you're quite mistaken about that. From the O.P.: "I would like to know if it has an implication regarding the **value of moral reasoning** .. it betrays something quite strong about **one's philosophical attitude** .. Does it reflect a **lack of seriousness or respect** for moral questions?" Etymology alone won't answer those queries. If I told you, "It would be a sin to downvote this question" – could you infer from that my philosphical attitude? Accurately deduce how seriously I regard moral questions? That would be stereotyping, not etymology.

Comment: @J.R. You're right - the OP does ask for that sort of insight. It seems that I forgot about that part of the question. Sorry about that. Hopefully a mathematician will drop by and provide us an answer, then.

Comment: @user867: Ah, well, the devil is in the details. At least now you're seeing why I thought this was worth posting as an answer in this case.

Comment: As one of those adamant Fundamentalists, I have no problem with people using theological metaphors to describe non-theological subjects. But HOW they use them can say something about their underlying philosophy. e.g. I've often heard people say, "oh, don't turn this technical debate into a religious argument", by which it is clear they mean "irrational and emotional". The clear implication is that they think religious discussion is inherently irrational. On the other hand, when I saw a book on economics titled "The Law and the Profits", I saw the pun on "the Law and the Prophets", a ...

Comment: ... term for the Hebrew Bible, and laughed along with the joke. My point being: some jokes and metaphors are all in good fun and we can all laugh along. Others indicate preconceptions or judgments. Compare to ethnic humor. I wouldn't say that anyone who begins a joke with "A black man walked into a bar ..." is a racist. But after hearing the end of the joke, I might conclude that.